# Sending Blob Messages to ActiveMQ with JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jms, blob, activemq-classic

As I am a starter in both programs, I had some research about sending messages to ActiveMQ with using JMS point-to-point sampler in JMeter and what I had is as below.What I want to do is the same thing but with the Blob Messages. How can I configure P2P sampler to be able to do that?

[image: jms point-to-point sampler]

[image: result]

Comment: Please post the images here instead of linking to imgur

Comment: It says you need at least 10 reputation to add images. That's why i linked them